# Application doesn't update its connection when SQL Azure Failover occurs until it's restarted

Tags: .net, azure-sql-database, failover

Changed our connection in the web.config to point to the failover group, and then trigger a failover in Azure. What I expected was that the application would have some errors for a while during the transition, but then it would continue to work and hit the new database.

Instead however it continues to hit the wrong database and gets a 'database is read-only' exception (because the database have switched and the one it was using is now readonly). If I restart the application, it works as intended.

Is there a connection string or application setting or something that will cause it to correctly refresh its connection without having to be restarted?

The application is a .NET web project.

Comment: Use read-write listener for OLTP workload: When performing OLTP operations, use <failover-group-name>.database.windows.net as the server URL and the connections are automatically directed to the primary. This URL does not change after the failover.
Note the failover involves updating the DNS record so the client connections are redirected to the new primary only after the client DNS cache is refreshed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-geo-replication-overview

Comment: I am using the failover group name in the connection string, it just doesn't update the server it's hitting until it's restarted, presumably because it only resolves the DNS IP once.

Comment: Are you using auto failover groups as described here(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-geo-replication-overview) or some thing else

Comment: Yes, I am. It works fine, in that if I keep resolving the database URL it updates its IP address when the failover is done, but my application seems to be still caching the DNS entry, so it does not failover